# Opencv - Close a specific contour

Tags: opencv, image-processing, contour, convex-hull

I'm dealing with an image and I need your help. After a lot of image processing I get this from a microscopic image. This is my pre-final thresholded image:

[image: unclosed contour]

As you can see there's a big **C** in the upper left corner. This should not be an open blob, it must be a closed one.

How can I achieve that with out modifying the rest? I was thinking on applying Convex Hull to that contour, **but I don't know how to apply to that and only that contour, with out even touching the others**.

I mean, maybe there's a "meassure" I can use to isolate this contour from the rest. Maybe a way to tell how convex/cancave it is or how big is the "hole" it delimits.

In further works maybe appears some other unclosed contours that I'll need to close, so don't focus it this particular case I'll need something I can use or adapt to other similar cases.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Draw contours on all the blobs. Select that particular blob using: `contour[1]` and mask the rest of the blobs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Jeru's answer is correct on the part where you want to close the contour once you have identified it, I think OP also wants to know how he can automatically identify the "C" blob without having to find out manually that's it the 29th contour.

Hence, I propose a method to identify it : compute the centroids of each shape and check if this centroid is inside the shape. It should be the case for blobs (circle) but not for "C"s.

```
img=cv2.imread(your_image,0)
if img is None:
     sys.exit("No input image") #good practice
res=np.copy(img) #just for visualisation purposes    

#finding the connectedComponents (each blob)
output=cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(img,8)
#centroid is sort of the "center of mass" of the object.
centroids=output[3]
#taking out the background
centroids=centroids[1:]


#for each centroid, check if it is inside the object
for centroid in centroids:
    if(img[int(centroid[1]),int(centroid[0])]==0):
        print(centroid) 
        #save it somewhere, then do what Jeru Luke proposes

    #an image with the centroids to visualize
    res[int(centroid[1]), int(centroid[0])]=100
```

This works for your code (I tried it out), but caveat, may not work for every "C form" especially if they are "fatter", as their centroid could well be inside them. I think there may be a better measure for convexity as you say, at least looking for such a measure seems the right direction for me.

Maybe you can try something like computing ConvexHull on all your objects (without modifying your input image), than measure the ratio between the object's area and the "convex hull around it"'s area, and if that ratio is under a certain threshold then you classify it as a "C" shape and modify it accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! a really smart solution!! I'll try that

Comment: plus 1 wonderful idea. But I think the proposal of using `convexHull` tops it off!!!

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution.

First, I found and drew contours on the threshold image given by you.

In the image, I figured out that the 29th contour is the one with the **C**. Hence I colored every contour apart from the 29th contour with black. The contour having the **C** alone was in white.

Code:

```
#---- finding all contours
contours, iji = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#---- Turning all contours black
cv2.drawContours(im1, contours, -1, (0,0,0), -1)

#---- Turning contour of interest alone white
cv2.drawContours(im1, contours, 29, (255, 255, 255), -1)
```

You are left with the blob of interest

[image]

Having isolated the required blob, I then performed morphological closing using the ellipse kernel for a certain number of iterations.

```
#---- k = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(30,30))
#---- closing = cv2.morphologyEx(opening, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, k)
#---- cv2.imshow("closed_img", closing)
```

[image]

The ball is now in your court! I learnt something as well! Have fun.

Comment: Thank you Jeru, but as pointed out by @Soltius, I need an automatic process

Comment: One more thing, could you post the code to achieve that? Specially the part where you apply *morphological closing using the ellipse kernel for a certain number of iterations*. If it's C++ better

Comment: I have the solution in python if it is fine with you

Comment: Thank you Jeru, I've manage to do it as @Soltius suggested and I've closed the contour using convexHull

Comment: `connectedComponents` is something new to me. Good thing he mentioned it :)

Comment: Jeru! could you post you python solution? I'm intrigued by this approach. I've never heard of it and I couldn't find it

Comment: @sebasira Right now I'm at home. I will share the code tomorrow once I reach my work place